# I { have been/went} to New York in 2015

Tags: time, past-vs-present-perfect

Which one is right?

> I have been to New York in 2015.

and

> I went to New York in 2015.

I think the first one is wrong and the second one is right.

but still, I am not sure if we can use 'in time' in present perfect.

Comment: The second is correct. New York is two words. the first **and** should be **or**. You **can** use the present perfect with /time/ if the time continues to today. In other words if it is *still* 2015! But it's 2021! This is right: "I went to New York in 2015 and I have been there twice in 2021" [This](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-perfect) may help.

Comment: The second is fine in its own but you could say something like "I had been to NY in 2015, but not recently."

Answer (score 1):

I have been to New York = I went to New York and returned after a short time.

I went to New York = I went to New York. I may or may not have stayed there.

“In” can be used with any time. For example “I plan to go to New York in 2025 at the latest”.